# Unable to encode .proto file into binary using protoc compiler types not defined

Tags: protobuf-net, protoc

I'm trying to convert the proto file into binary for an HTTP request payload, however, I'm receiving an error from protoc compiler tool, returning type not defined. I was not able to find any documentation on the type definitions used alongside --encode=.

I've tried specifying different types in the --encode, but the information I was finding was irrelevant. Other things I've tried specifying the proto message from the .proto file ``` message **DeviceAuthRequest** { }

```
protoc --encode=projname.auth TEST.proto > TEST.bin
Type not defined: projname.auth
```

```
protoc --encode=DeviceAuthRequest TEST.proto > TEST.bin
```

What the the actual types for the --encode and --decode? I have a source code and compiled code in C#. Looking for a way of crafting payload with modified data in the proto file.

Comment: I'm confused... You say you have the C#... Can't you just load (deaerialize) the data using the C# generated code, change the data *as objects*, and serialize it again?

Comment: Rather than modifying generated C# code, I'd prefer to use protoc files as I will need to make frequent changes to params across multiple .proto files. `protoc --encode=[package].[message] test.proto > test.bin` I was able to execute the protoc without message type errors however, upon execution, the protoc cli would just hang without generating binary file.

Comment: but you're only trying to change the *data* right? you wouldn't need to *modify* the generated files *at all*; you'd just write about 3 lines that deserializes, mutates, and serializes; am I misundertanding the question?

Comment: That's correct, it's a matter of modifying the actual data, to ensure properly formatted payloads are sent to the API accordingly to the proto files. All I have access it to the API accepting protobuf messages and not the client-side application sending the messages, so I will be generating my own data and mutating it accordingly.

Comment: I'm trying the following which still gives me parsing errors, not entirely sure what I've gotten wrong with a format. Receiving the following:input:1:12: Expected identifier, got: ""5eb94f9c-ee3e-476a-ada9-4a84cf72ff28"".
Failed to parse input.`


`protoc --encode packagetest.demo demo.proto < demo.txt > demo.bin`


`DemoIds: {"5eb94f9c-ee3e-476a-ada9-4a84cf72ff28"}
SentTimeUtc: "2019-10-18T17:15:00Z"
ContextId: 123123123`

proto demo file
```message demo { repeated UserGuid DemoIds = 1; google.protobufTimestamp SentTimeUtc = 2; int32 ContextId = 3}```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which proto schema you are referring to, but the syntax should look like (an example for generating the carrier identifiers under Android with `protoc` version 3.6.1):

```
cat carrier_list.textpb | protoc --encode=carrierIdentification.CarrierList -I/home/osboxes/Documents/ carrierId.proto > test.pb
```

I do not see any input in your example. `protoc`  reads the input from standard in so you have to pipe in some data, e.g. by using the `cat` command. I also do not see any includes. You have to pass the includes with `-I` where the proto files are searched. This is also missing in your examples. Use an absolute path here, if you face any problems.

The `carrierId.proto` file looks like

```
syntax = "proto2";

package carrierIdentification;

option java_package = "com.android.internal.telephony";
option java_outer_classname = "CarrierIdProto";

// A complete list of carriers
message CarrierList {
  // A collection of carriers. one entry for one carrier.
  repeated CarrierId carrier_id = 1;
  // Version number of current carrier list
  optional int32 version = 2;
};
```

So, when rerencing the proto file your have to use the .(dot).carrierIdentification.CarrierList.